# deleting all but one files using batch file not working

Tags: batch-file

I have batch script that runs in WIn 7 command prompt.
it needs to delete all the files in folder except file with ".a" extension.
I tried following code

```
for /F %%I in ("*") DO if not (%%~xI=="a") del /q %%I
```

It deletes all files.
I tried following:

```
for /F %%I in ("*") DO if not (%%~xI==a) del /q %%I
```

no luck. Where am I wrong?

sedy

Comment: Try: `for %%I in (*) DO if not %%~xI == .a del /q %%I`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for /F` loops consider sets in quotes to be strings, so you are saying to parse the string "*", which results in the delete command being interpreted as `del /q *`, which deletes everything.

Use `for /F %%I in ('dir /b')` instead, which will process based on the list of files in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%f in (`dir /b .\d\*`) do (
    if not %%~xf equ .a (echo deleting %%f)
)
```